# Manifest.mf access issue

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I made changes to build.xml (ANT) to add information about author,time stamp,  version and trying to access same information from .mf file however  getting **null** values from newly added java code.

I am expecting values for Build-By,Build-Date and Build-Version as it's in Manifest.

Current Output

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.2
Created-By: 1.3.1_16-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: null
Built-Date: null
Build-Version: null
```

Manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_73-b02 (Oracle Corporation)
Built-By: mindpeace
Built-Date: 201604110952
Build-Version: 5.1
```

Java Code

```
try {
            mf.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
            Attributes atts = mf.getMainAttributes();
            System.out.println("Manifest-Version: " + atts.getValue("Manifest-Version"));
            System.out.println("Ant-Version: " + atts.getValue("Ant-Version"));
            System.out.println("Created-By: " + atts.getValue("Created-By"));
            System.out.println("Built-By: " + atts.getValue("Built-By"));
            System.out.println("Built-Date: " + atts.getValue("Built-Date"));
            System.out.println("Build-Version: " + atts.getValue("Build-Version"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the jar's manifest actually has the new attributes, as defined in your build.xml file?

Comment: @ManoDestra - Yes, Manifest has all information I wants to access.

Comment: Check the attribute names for a match in that case. You refer to both Build-Date and Built-Date above, for instance. Make sure you're referring to the attribute names correctly and by the correct case.

Comment: You get version `1.6.2` while your manifest states `1.9.4`? That looks like you're reading the wrong file.

Comment: Yeah, you're using a contextclassloader, so make sure that you're accessing the correct JAR's manifest, of course.

Comment: That's correct!! somehow my java code referring to supporting jar file from lib directory not actual jar file